# what is the best way to initialize object with try, catch block without using block in c#

Tags: c#, try-catch

I have one method, in which I want to initialize object (e.g. fetches Department List) of one Class and use that same in try/catch block (e.g. returns that Department List) and then want to set it to null.

1. One way

   ```
   public List<Departments> GetAllDepartments()
   {
       List<Departments> listDepartments = null;
       try
       {
           listDepartments = IDepartment.GetAllDepartments();

           return listDepartments;
       }
       catch (System.Exception ex)
       {
           throw ex;
       }
       finally
       {
           listDepartments = null;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Another way

   ```
   public List<Departments> GetAllDepartments()
   {
       try
       {
           List<Departments> listDepartments = IDepartment.GetAllDepartments();

           return listDepartments;
       }
       catch (System.Exception ex)
       {
           throw ex;
       }
   }
   ```

Which one is best? if any other way, please let me know. I have discussed this same with my office mates, one told me that in 1 method, I forces to compiler to initializes the object (here listDepartment) to set first with null and then forces to compile with database object.

Note: I could not able to use IDisposable.

I am sorry, that I could not able to raise the question very clear in first run. this is just an example of department, actually there are many other filters and other objects in my method. my main concern is, how the compiler will work when first line it catches like ' List listx = null; ' and listx = new xClass(); or listx = [database call]. as my office mates told me this is an extra overhead for compiler. I would like to clear my this doubt here.

---

Please forget the above question

Here I am redefining my question.

Question:
I and one of my office mate has debate about initialize the object and set it null once it has been utilized.

I suggest him the below way to get release the object once it has been utilized:

```
public string something()
{
    Department objDepartment = null;

    try
    {
        objDepartment = new Department();
    }
    catch
    .
    .
    .
    finally
    {
       objDepartment = null;
    }
}
```

my office mate told me that, very first here i am forces to .net compiler to initialize the objDepartment with null and after that inside the try block I again force to .net compiler to initialize the objDepartment with actual instance. so according to him the code should be:

```
public string something()
{

    try
    {
        Department objDepartment = new Department();
    }
    catch
    .
    .
    .
}
```

so my question here is: how can i release the object once it has been utilize, as objDepartment will not be available in finally block as its scope is now only inside the try block only. and if any other ways to initialize, use it and release it finally.

and the other condition is that, I could not use IDisposable.

And thanks to all who participated and give the answers. And one more time I expecting your active participation.

Comment: Why are you catching exceptions simply to rethrow them? You will lose the stack trace this way.

Comment: Why do you create `listDepartments` anyway instead of simple `return IDepartment.GetAllDepartments();`?

Comment: Why are you setting a local variable to null at the end of a method? What do you expect that to achieve? Why is your method body not just `return IDepartment.GetAllDepartments();`?

Comment: @DenielKelley  Thank you, but if you give some code example then its really helpful.

Comment: If you need to re throw the exceptions use only throw instead, which preserves the stack trace.

Comment: @erikduvet yes, indeed, do not use "throw ex;". Write only "throw;" - that way you preserve the stack trace. There is also no point in setting a local variable to null in the finally block since the variable does not exist after you return from the method.

Comment: @ tdragon & Jon Skeet, this is just an example, there were so many filters and number of objects in one method. my concern is more regarding Compiler works for initialize first with null and then initialize with actual instance.

Comment: mihir I'm a bit confused by the idea behind your code/question. you want to return either the result or null (if an exception occurs) if I understand you correctly but teh "throw ex" results in nothing at all returned and instead an exception being given to the caller method. So what is it that you really want there as behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

```
public List<Departments> GetAllDepartments()
{
    return IDepartment.GetAllDepartments();
}
```

That is the **only** useful code in your question. There is no point or benefit in setting a local (aka method-variable) to `null` before exiting; that serves **no purpose**, and does not represent "collection" or anything remotely similar - so there is no point in the `finally`. The `catch` block is equally useless, unless your explicit intent is to destroy your own stack-trace.

If you need to do extra code on the object prior to returning it:

```
public List<Departments> GetAllDepartments()
{
    var departments = IDepartment.GetAllDepartments();
    // TODO: do stuff with "departments" here
    return departments;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not doing any custom exception try and catch doesn't make any sense in this case. Hence you can use code as bellow.

```
public List<Departments> GetAllDepartments()
{

        return IDepartment.GetAllDepartments();
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the below code.It will avoid multiple return statement.

```
 public List<Departments> GetAllDepartments()
    {
        List<Departments> listDepartments = null;
        try
        {
            listDepartments = IDepartment.GetAllDepartments();       
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
           //Handle your exception
        }
        return listDepartments; 
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this addresses the question

Comment: It does not. Typicall "lets post something and hope" answer.

Answer (score -4):

```
 public List<Departments> GetAllDepartments()
        {
            try
            {
                return IDepartment.GetAllDepartments();


            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
              //  throw ex;  dont throw the same caugted exception
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not only it swallows the exception, but it is usually quite a bad practice to catch just System.Exception.

Comment: @MarcGravell "use that same in try/catch block" this from the question

Comment: @BinsonEldhose which says nothing whatsoever about swallowing the exception;

Comment: All, what i focused in this question is ,how to optimize the initialization of the object and return. The commented section in the catch block was an advice. I believe throwing the same exception is bad idea.instead of throwing it is better to modifying or log etc.